# Target elements that come after a specific element with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using Javascript/jQuery or a CSS selector, how would I target elements that come after a specific element? To be clear, I don't mean directly after (adjacent to), I mean any and all matching elements that exist further down the page.

Imagine a group of `<p>`s:

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p id="special">Ipsum</p>
<p>Dolor</p>
<p>Sit</p>
<p>Amet</p>
```

Now I want to target all of the `<p>`s that come after `p#special`... so the ones with content "Dolor", "Sit", and "Amet". I want there to be some selector available like:

```
$('p#special::allAfter p').each(...
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `$('p#special').nextAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextAll()` is a jQuery function that you are looking for.

See this documentation:https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: Thanks @Sam. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [general sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) selector in CSS

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

```css
#special ~ p {color: red}
```

```html
<p>Lorem</p>
<p id="special">Ipsum</p>
<p>Dolor</p>
<p>Sit</p>
<p>Amet</p>
```

In jQuery it's called the ["Next Siblings Selector "](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

```
$('#special ~ p')
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

next() https://api.jquery.com/next/

nextall() https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

nextuntil() https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ (Might more useful)

$( "p#special" ).next().css( "background-color", "red" );

Answer (score 0):

If all the elements are in the same parent, you can just use the [General Sibling Combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators):

```css
#special ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem</p>
<p id="special">Ipsum</p>
<p>Dolor</p>
<p>Sit</p>
<p>Amet</p>
```

However, then the `<p>` does have to be a **sibling**.

Otherwise, if you want to select every p further down the page, no matter if it's a sibling or not, you'll have to use JS:

```js
var para = document.querySelectorAll("p"), //Get p's
  addColor = false;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(para, function(p) {
  //Loop through paragraphs

  //If addColor is true, add color to paragraph
  if (addColor) p.style.color = "red";

  //If the current paragraphs id is special, set addColor to true
  if (p.id == "special") addColor = true;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p id="special">Test</p>
</div>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, in jQuery:

```js
var para = $("p"),
  addColor = false;

para.each(function() {
  if (addColor) this.style.color = "red";
  if (this.id === "special") addColor = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p id="special">Test</p>
</div>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `~` selector.

In your case:

```
p#special ~ p
```